# Getting TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def hourglassSum():
    for i in range(0,6):
        arr1=map(int,input().split())
        arr=list(arr1)
    sum=[]
for i in range(len(arr)-2):
        for j in range(len(arr)-2):
            sum.append(arr[i][j]+arr[i][j+1]+arr[i][j+2]+arr[i+1][j]+arr[i+2][j]+arr[i+2][j+1]+arr[i+2][j+2])

    maxi=max(sum)
    print(maxi)

hourglassSum()
```

This code shows the following error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

How to fix it?

Comment: post complete error message

Comment: Please provide objective of this function too

Comment: Also, it seems there is some indentation problems in your code

Comment: That type of error means that you are trying to do something like 10[0] or similar. Make sure that the list “arr” is in fact a 2D list, otherwise you will get this error. To do this I suggest just printing it after you create the “sum” variable

Comment: `arr` is just a list (can be seen from `arr=list(map(int,input().split()))`). When you do `arr[i]` you get an int. So by doing `arr[i][j]` you are trying to access the int which is not possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that's what you're looking for:

```py
def hourglassSum():
    arr = []
    for i in range(0,6):
        arr1=map(int,input().split())
        arr.append(list(arr1))
    sum=[]
    for i in range(len(arr)-2):
        for j in range(min(len(arr[i]), len(arr[i+1]), len(arr[i+2]))-2):
            sum.append(arr[i][j]+arr[i][j+1]+arr[i][j+2]+arr[i+1][j]+arr[i+2][j]+arr[i+2][j+1]+arr[i+2][j+2])

    maxi=max(sum)
    print(maxi)
```

Two notes:

(1) you want to persist each iteration of the first loop, what you were doing was just overwriting your variable with each iteration

(2) while iterating across different elements of elements of your base list - always make sure you won't run into index out of bounds exception - I presume your approach was to put in 6x6 elements - so it's just to mitigate eventual discrepancies